# Clarification on spf record DNS lookup limit

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I am trying to get clear on how the 10 DNS lookup for spf records are done. I have a client that claims they have reached the maximum - my understanding is that there would be recursive dns lookups for domain names but not IP addresses?

The spf record is:

```
 v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:sendgrid.net include:mailgun.org include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

My inspection of each of these domains' spf records just show addresses.

I am counting 5 DNS lookup of the 10 limit. Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC4408 s10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-10.1) says

> SPF implementations MUST limit the number of mechanisms and modifiers
> that do DNS lookups to at most 10 per SPF check, including any
> lookups caused by the use of the "include" mechanism

So the first lookup is the one to get your record.  Then there are five `include`s to look up.  Of those, three simply return address ranges, but two (`mailgun.org` and `spf.protection.outlook.com`) have themselves each `include`d two more records to look up (the former has them both in the main SPF record, the latter nests them).

That is a total of ten, which is indeed the limit.

Comment: Ah looks like I missed those. Thank you for clarifying.